# Bash: space as a key in an associative array

Tags: bash, variable, array, assignment

This code in Bash

```
s="There are seven pencil"
declare -A A
while IFS= read -rn1 a; do
 [ -z "$a" ] || [ -n "${A[$a]}" ] && continue
 printf %s "$a"
 ((A[$a]++))    # A[$a]=x
done <<<"$s"
echo
```

produces this line

```
Ther a svn pcil
```

All spaces printed out. Is this behaviour documented or in any other way expected?

Still, when `((A[$a]++))` is replaced with `A[$a]=x`, the output changes to

```
Ther asvnpcil
```

So this time only the first space is printed.

**What's the difference?**

This is in GNU bash, version 4.4.12(1)-release (x86_64-pc-linux-gnu).

---

There's a third operation to compare to, namely `let "A[$a]=x"`. Strangely, it falls somewhere in between the former two. It produces the line with all spaces, ie. `Ther a svn pcil`. But using the reduction from [isaac's answer](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/419506/181255), it behaves like the `A[$a]=x` assignment:

```
$ unset A; declare -A A; let "A[' ']++"; declare -p A
declare -A A=([" "]="1" )
```

---

Eventually, I've sent a bug report with this. [Here's its thread.](http://lists.gnu.org/archive/html/bug-bash/2018-01/msg00079.html)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The core issue is in using arithmetic to declare a variable.

Replace:

```
(( A[$a]++ ))
```

with

```
declare -A A["$a"]=1
```

And the repeated spaces are removed.

---

It seems to me to be a bug, an space fails to create the variable:

```
$ declare -A A; (( A[" "]++ )); declare -p A
declare -A A
```

---

Addressing your edit after I posted the above answer:

**What's the difference?**

That an assignment does declare the variable as part of the array:

```
$ unset A; declare -A A; A[" "]=1 ; declare -p A
declare -A A=([" "]="1" )
```

while an arithmetic expansion **fails** to do the equivalent:

```
$ unset A; declare -A A; (( A[" "]=1 )); declare -p A
declare -A A
```

Comment: I agree with the difference, and I agree that it looks like a bug. I have one more reference: `declare -A A; let "A[' ']++"; declare -p A` gives `declare -A A=([" "]="1" )`.

Comment: I have doubts about the syntax in this line of your answer: `declare -A A["$a"]=1`. It looks to me like declaring another associative array. Simple `declare A["$a"]=1` makes the change too.

Comment: @tomasz Both syntaxes are valid **and** equivalent. No it is not declaring a new variable, the name is still `A` for both declarations.

Comment: Strangely, `let "A[$a]=x"` produces all spaces in the original context. (I updated my question.)

Comment: Testing with `unset A; a=" ";declare -A A; let "A[$a]=x"; declare -p A` still **fails** to create the variable, thus all spaces is the expected result. @tomasz

Comment: Well done! You simplify very well.

Comment: I've sent a bug report. It seems that's it.